# Globally applying JSON Serializer Settings in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

`Entity Framework Navigation` properties are causing a **"Circular Object Reference"** exception when my `Kendo Grid` attempts to serialize a collection in my `View Model`.  We are using `Newtonsoft.JSON`, so I wanted to (globally) set the **"ReferenceLoopHandling"** to **"Ignore"** in my `Application_Start()`.

Oddly, ASP.NET doesn't seem to be honoring the setting...so I still get the exception.

**...ANY IDEAS?**

VERSIONS:

- Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc (5.2.3.0)
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi (5.2.3)
- Newtonsoft.Json (10.0.3)

**SAMPLE APPLICATION_START:**
Moving to the call to the *top* or *bottom* doesn't change the outcome...

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    LoadSiteMap();

    var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
}
```

**SAMPLE RAZOR MARKUP:**
Notice the "BindTo" option...

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RTUDeviceControlRoomAlarm>()
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
                      .Visible(false);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.RTUDeviceId)
                      .Visible(false);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.Register)
                      .Title("Register")
                      .Width(50);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.Description)
                      .Title("Description")
                      .Width(100);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.LowLowLimitOFF)
                      .Title("LL Limit/OFF")
                      .Width(50);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.LowLowLimitON)
                      .Title("LL Limit/ON")
                      .Width(50);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.HiLimit)
                      .Title("Hi Limit")
                      .Width(50);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.HiHiLimit)
                      .Title("HH Limit")
                      .Width(50);
                  columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(70);
              })
              .Name("gridControlRoomAlarms")
              .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
              .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
              .Sortable()
              .Scrollable()
              .BindTo(Model.RTUDeviceControlRoomAlarms)
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
                                                  .PageSize(50)
                                                  .Model(model => { model.Id(m => m.Id); })
                                                  .Create(update => update.Action("Create", "ControlRoomAlarm", new { Area = "Documents" }))
                                                  .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "ControlRoomAlarm", new { Area = "Documents" }))
                                                  .Destroy(update => update.Action("Destroy", "ControlRoomAlarm", new { Area = "Documents" }))
                                                  )
              .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "", @style = "height: 400px;" }))
```

**UPDATE:**
Have also tried...

- `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;`

Comment: Do you have an answer for this? I'm also experiencing the same issue.

Comment: No...not yet.  I am still experiencing the issue.  Which is why I haven't marked this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this configuration in your `Application_Start()` as last line:

```
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
```

See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm and be careful of possible side effect in your code

Comment: Do I keep the "ReferenceLoopHandling" piece alongside your suggestion?

Comment: NOPE: "A circular reference was detected while serializing" (thanks though)